# Why does dynamic allocation release "twice" when head_node(first_node) of the singly linked list initialize?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, free

I want to know the reason for `twice of dynamic allocation release.`
I think, use `free function` just one time when initializing of headnode.

Here is the code!! :)

```
int freeList(headNode* h){
    listNode* p = h->first;
    listNode* prev = NULL;   
    
    while(p != NULL) {      
        prev = p;           
        p = p->link;         
        free(prev);    /* Here is a problem
                        What is a few errors with just coding free(prev)? */    
    }
    free(h);  /* Here is a problem */  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean why we have to iterate to free the whole list?

Comment: *"What is a few errors..."*: I don't understand this comment in your code. Are you asking about errors that you are getting? Or do you get errors when you change the code? Is your code having problems right now?

Comment: *"...when head_node(first node) of the singly list initialise"*: the code you show has nothing to do with the initialisation of the singly list... I don't understand this part of the subject and how it relates to your code?

Comment: Why do you post a [copy of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122502/why-does-dynamic-allocation-release-twice-when-the-singly-linked-list-initiali) without answering the comments here and improving your question *here*?

Answer (score 0):

`free(prev)` and `free(h)` are about different data structures:

- `free(prev)` is freeing the memory of a `listNode` instance
- `free(h)` is freeing the memory of a `headNode` instance.

`headNode` is a bit of a confusing name, as I assume that structure does not actually represent the *first* node in a list, but is the "container" for the list. It has a `first` pointer which may be `NULL` (in case the represented linked list is empty), or may be a pointer to the first node. Either way, a `headNode` instance is something different than the instance of the first node it *might* refer to (only when the represented linked list is not empty).

So your loop frees the memory of all the nodes in the list, while the final call to `free` is about the `headNode` instance, which is not a node *of* the linked list, but is the container *for* the linked list.